# Why is "Jonathan Wild" spelt "Ionathan Wild" in this ticket to his 1725 hanging?

Tags: england

The ticket: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonathan_Wild#/media/File:Ticket_to_the_hanging_of_Jonathan_Wild.jpg

I was thinking it might be to indicate the etymology of the word from some language, but I don't know how likely that is and the rules say I need more characters.

Comment: Because it is being spelt in "*mock Latin*", where the letter "J" has not yet been introduced to the alphabet.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any idea why the person who wrote this chose to mock Latinise his first name?

Answer (score 4):

It's probably a case of move along nothing to see here, or some stylistic effect to make it look latin, as suggested by Pieter in his comment.

[I and J used to be used interchangeably](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J#History). It's only during the Renaissance (Gian Giorgio Trissino in 1524) that the idea of using the two letters to represent different sounds emerged. The first English book to make the distinction between the two was "English Grammar" by Charles Butler in 1633 (1634? sources don't seem to agree). On top of this, spelling [wasn't entirely normalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English-language_spelling_reform#History) at the time.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: For some reason the Roman Latin alphabet did not distinguish between 'i' and 'j' but used one letter for both. Likewise 'v' stood either for our 'u' or 'w' (they apparently did not need a symbol for our 'v' sound). Hence in Roman inscriptions 'Julius' (as in Julius Caesar) would be written JVLIVS